# Select one value from two different select query result (Oracle) based on first select query result

Tags: sql, oracle

Please amend the below query for my requirement. Please find code below.

```
CASE Select NVL(Sum(Value1+value2 +value3),0) from Table1 Where Step = 4
WHEN 0 THEN (Select Sum(Value1) from Table1 Where Step < 4)
Else NVL(Sum(Value1 + value2 + value3) END AS "SumValue"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your go. Use `subquery`.

```
select case when t1.val = 0 then t1.val2 else t1.val3 end as "SumValue"
from
    (Select NVL(Sum(case when step = 4 then Value1+value2+value3 else 0 end),0) val
        , Sum(case when step < 4 then Value1 else 0 end) val2
        , Sum(Value1+value2+value3) val3 from Table1) t1
```

Comment: Thanks Metal, two different where clause, First query sum three columns value in one record, second query sum one column value in three records (step is consider as row), please help to amend